# Azure Portal - adding role groups is not working properly

Tags: azure

I'm trying to add a Developers group to the Reader role, for a Website, in the new Azure Portal and assign users to that group.

When I add a specific user to the Reader role of a Website the user can see everything fine but when I remove that user and add them to the Developers group the Website doesn't show up for them in the portal.

Is there a step I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

I just tried the same steps:

- Added a new group 'Developers' to Azure AD
- Assigned user A to this group
- Assigned this group to Readers role of a website
- Logged in with user A to portal.azure.com

User A can now see the website.

So it works as expected.

Update: when using a Microsoft Account (Microsoft Live Id), I have the same issue and that user is not able to see the website. Looks like a bug. A workaround would be to use an Azure AD user.

Comment: Just to be clear. You did all of this in manage.windowsazure.com under Active Directory? Also was the user a Microsoft Live user? When I log in with User A I can't even see "Websites" in the Browse blade of the portal...

Comment: In manage.windowsazure.com:

1. Added a new group 'Developers' to Azure AD
2. Created a new User 'A' in Azure AD
3. Assigned user A to this group
4. Assigned this group to Readers role of a website

In portal.azure.com
5. Logged in with user A to portal.azure.com

Comment: I now tried the same with a Microsoft Account (Microsoft Live) and experienced the same issues you have. Seems to be a bug. I have updated the answer to reflect this. Are you able to switch to Azure AD Users?